# How can a frontend hosted on cloudfront access appsync when CORS should be block the call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Just a general question about how this works in AWS. I didn't find the solution explained anywhere straight to the point.

I have a frontend hosted over cloudfront at one url and an AWS Appsync graphql api for the backend which exposes a seperate public url. The graphql api is managed by AWS Amplify the cloudfront distribution separately, in case it matters.

Now i am wondering how it is possible that the frontend can just call the appsync api? Shouldn't the CORS block access to the graphql api since they are on two different urls? Where is the magic happening?